# Click alert button to show MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Trying to use MFMailComposeViewController when click alert button. But when I click alert button, controller doesn't pop-up. The code is below. I used extension and I'm trying to call sendmail function when clicking alert button.

```
extension Alert:MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendmail(){
        let mailComposeViewController = configureMailController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
            VC?.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            showMailError()
        }
    }

    func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = VC as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["**"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("**")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("\n\n\n\nModel: \nSistem versiyon: )\nuygulamaversiyon:", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showMailError() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send email", message: "Your device could not send email", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
        let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
        VC?.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you call `configureMailController()` before doing `if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {`? There's no reason to create the controller before knowing whether you should use it or not.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I didn't realize that.

Comment: Need more information to help. What are the values of `storyboard` and `VC` in the if statement? Does the error show or does nothing at all happen?

Comment: Also, your `VC` is never presented onto any view hierarchy with this code. I think you are seeing nothing at all, and this is probably why. It will also be released after this if goes out of scope. Further down the line, in `configureMailController`, your `VC` delegate wont be able to do anything since you have no reference to it, it will get released as well

Comment: VC is my initialView Controller, I tried to reach my initialVC via storyboard. and also app has one ViewController which named MainVC.  The error is: 2018-01-23 21:37:10.696330+0300 Appname[44710:3117371] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID:boundle-id, source account management: 1

Comment: You're creating a new one each time you call `instantiateViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to present the mail view controller (and also the error alert) on a new view controller which you create with `instantiateViewController`. Since this new VC itself is not part of your app's VC hierarchy, neither it nor the mail VC will appear on screen.

To make this work, you can either pass a view controller which *is* part of your app into your `sendmail` method:

```
func sendmail(_ root: UIViewController) {
  ...
  root.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ...
```

Or you can use a globally accessible VC of your app; in a simple app using the root VC should work:

```
func sendmail() {
  ...
  let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
  root?.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ...
```

I'd suggest the first approach because it is more flexible (e.g. it allows you to open your mail screen anywhere, even when your VC hierarchy gets more complex).