# getting error MFMailComposeViewController: Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift 4 for an iOS project, Testing device is iOS 11. 
I am trying to send email like this:

```
func sendEmail(mailBody : String) {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setMessageBody(mailBody, isHTML: false)

            self.present(mail, animated: true)
        } else {
            // show failure alert
        }
    }
```

But it is producing this:

```
[MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: com.s-dev, source account management: 1
```

why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFMailComposeViewController error \[MC\] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608727/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-error-mc-filtering-mail-sheet-accounts-for-bundle)